# How to add transparent border around Grid rows?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

Have a grid inside of a grid.  Need the inner grid to have a transparent border so that the outer grid's background color shows.

So far:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Rectangle Fill="#999999" Grid.Column="0" ></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Column="1"></Rectangle>

    <Grid x:Name="gridLeft" Grid.Column="0" Background="#DFDFDF">
<Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="30" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1"></Border>

        <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Style="{StaticResource RightGridLine}"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource RightGridLine}"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource RightGridLine}"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2"  Grid.RowSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource RightGridLine}"></Rectangle>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 </Grid>
```

However, since the transparent border above is in the inner grid it just shows the inner grid's background color, instead of the outer grid's background color.

[image]

Comment: I see one Grid, maybe a quick MSPaint doodle image or something to help visualize what you're after?

Comment: @ChrisW. I updated it.

Comment: Is the gray supposed to be transparent or the blue?

Comment: @ChrisW. The gray is the color I want to see between the gaps (not transparent).  I just figured I needed some kind of transparent element to create the gaps?

Comment: Ah ok so the black bars should be gray gaps making the blue boxes separated?

Comment: @ChrisW. - The black bars are black bars that separate each column.  They are suppose to be black :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if I'm understanding right, what you *want* is something like what you would normally use Opacity Mask for, but you don't have that option in WinRT apps. So you're left with organizing things based on your needs. So as a quick example, something more like this would suit you.

```
<Grid Width="500" Background="Gray">

  <Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF0066FF"/>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Rectangle/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="4"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="6"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Something"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="Something"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Text="Something"/>

  </Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]